# How to make JSON having loop inside lopp

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

I have following table client_question table

```
+----+------------+---------+-----+------+------+
| id | is_deleted | version | cid | pqid | qtid |
+----+------------+---------+-----+------+------+
|  1 |            |       0 |   1 |    1 |    1 |
|  2 |            |       0 |   1 |    2 |    4 |
|  3 |            |       0 |   1 |    2 |    4 |
+----+------------+---------+-----+------+------+
```

This is Parent_question table

```
+----+------------+---------+-----+------+
| id | is_deleted | version | pid | qid  |
+----+------------+---------+-----+------+
|  1 |            |       0 |   1 |    1 |
|  2 |            |       0 |   1 |    2 |
|  3 |            |       0 |   1 |    3 |
|  4 |            |       0 |   1 |    4 |
|  5 |            |       0 |   1 |    5 |
|  6 |            |       0 |   1 |    6 |
|  7 |            |       0 |   2 |    7 |
|  8 |            |       0 |   2 |    1 |
|  9 |            |       0 |   2 |    2 |
| 10 |            |       0 |   2 |    8 |
| 11 |            |       0 |   3 |    9 |
| 12 |            |       0 |   3 |    1 |
| 13 |            |       0 |   3 |   10 |
| 14 |            |       0 |   3 |   11 |
| 15 |            |       0 |   4 |   12 |
+----+------------+---------+-----+------+
```

And this is question_option

```
+----+------------+-----------+---------+
| id | is_deleted | name      | version |
+----+------------+-----------+---------+
|  1 |            | Excellent |       0 |
|  2 |            | Good      |       0 |
|  3 |            | Fair      |       0 |
|  4 |            | Poor      |       0 |
+----+------------+-----------+---------+
```

I want to retrieve JSON and send to front end via ajax so
I tried this way

```
public List<ClientQuestionOption> getSavedQuestionOptions(Long parentId,long clientId)
{
    Client client = (Client) entityManagerUtil.find(Client.class, clientId);
    List<ClientQuestionOption>  questionsList =     (List<ClientQuestionOption>)serviceClientDaoImpl.getSavedQuestionOptionsList(parentId,client);
    System.out.println("The size is nnnnnnnnnn "+questionsList.size());
    List optionsList =new ArrayList();

    for(int i=0;i<questionsList.size();i++)
    {
        //optionsList.add(questionsList.get(i).getCqid().getId());
        //optionsList.add(questionsList.get(i).getOid().getName());
        Map map=new HashMap();
        map.put("qid", questionsList.get(i).getCqid().getPqid().getQid().getId());
        map.put("name", questionsList.get(i).getOid().getName());
        optionsList.add(map);

    }
return optionsList;

}
```

The JSON i got is like this

```
[
{
name: "Excellent",
qid: 2
},
{
name: "Poor",
qid: 2
}
],
```

But I want JSON like this

```
 {
      "options": [
        "Poot",
        "Excellent"
      ],
      "qid": 2
    },
```

Can anybody please tell me how to do so?

**edit**

Following way I am doing to make JSON

```
    JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
List optionslist=null;
optionslist=(List<ClientQuestionOption>)serviceClientServiceImpl.getSavedQuestionOptions(parentId , Long.valueOf(clientId) );
    object.accumulate("optionslist",optionslist );

    return object.toString();
```

Comment: Start by not using raw types (i.e. not use `List` and `Map`, but `List<Map<String, String>>`, and you'll find that your code doesn't compile anymore, because you're not returning the right list.

Comment: @JBNizet can you please tell me how to do?

Comment: I just did. Don't declare `optionsList` as `List`. Declare it as `List<Map<String, String>>`. Don't declare `map` as `Map`. Declare it as `Map<String, String>`.

Answer (score 0):

First, realise what the function returns (`ArrayList`) is not `JSON` at all. It seems that happens elsewhere. You'll need to replace `JsonObject()` with `JsonArray()` to change the `[..]` to '{..}`.

Second, to do the grouping per `qid` you could write a function that has `List<ClientQuestionOption>` as input ánd output.

Answer (score 0):

You should check google GSON project, and here is what your code will look like:

```
public class ClientQuestionOption {
    String name;
    int qid;

    public ClientQuestionOption() {
    }

    public ClientQuestionOption(String name, int qid) {
        this.name = name;
        this.qid = qid;
    }
}
```

and then use it this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<ClientQuestionOption> questionOptions = Arrays.asList(
            new ClientQuestionOption("Excellent", 1),
            new ClientQuestionOption("Excellent", 2),
            new ClientQuestionOption("Poor", 3)
    );

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    System.out.println(gson.toJson(questionOptions));
}
```

You only need to have Class with same names of fields (or declar Qualifier) and gson will handle conversion from/to json.

here is the output for the above code:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Excellent",
    "qid": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Excellent",
    "qid": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Poor",
    "qid": 3
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering,Now I have added the JSON code